# What's a good way to document Hydra configs?

Tags: fb-hydra

In `argparse` you provide help alongside the definition of the argument. This helps keep the doc up-to-date with the args.

Is there an option to do something similar in Hydra? Or some other preferred way for documenting the options, without having to list them manually within the `hydra/help` message?

**Edit**: this becomes an even greater problem when using `call`/`instantiate` and the config options depend on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now we recommend using `hydra/help`. We do have a feature request, feel free to follow/contribute to the discussions here https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/633.

Thanks!